# Make dnsmasq not altering resolv.conf

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

Every time I (re)start dnsmasq it replaces `/etc/resolv.conf` with `nameserver 127.0.0.1 ...`.

However that maschine has not to use the local DNS service. (Please don't ask why, the whole environment is like it is...)

How do I actually prevent dnsmasq from touching `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Neither removing `resolvconf` nor `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` is an option.

Answer (score 6):

dnsmasq itself is not altering resolv.conf
If you have your configuration file and start it manually via `dnsmasq -d -C <yourconfig>` you see that.

This behaviour comes from systemd unit on debian and probably on ubuntu systems and perhaps on other distributions.

Stop dnsmasq via `sudo systemctl stop dnsmasq` (because otherwise changed /etc/resolv.conf won't be restored)
edit `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dnsmasq.service`
and comment out both lines

```
#ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf
#ExecStop=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-stop-resolvconf
```

exec `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

after that you can start dnsmasq and your /etc/resolv.conf file won't be changed by dnsmasq

Answer (score 2):

You can have `dnsmasq` use a different `resolv.conf` file, so when `/etc/resolv.conf` points to 127.0.0.1, `dnsmasq` will actually just use the other `resolv.conf` file and leave `/etc/resolv.conf` alone.

Add the following line to your `dnsmasq.conf` file:

```
resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-resolv.conf
```

And then create the file `/etc/dnsmasq.d/dnsmasq-resolv.conf` to look something like this:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.

Comment: So, it looks like I missed something. I'm guessing it's related to your DNS configuration, and that you have a "real" DNS server listening on 127.0.0.1, other than `dnsmasq`, which is why `/etc/resolv.conf` cannot point to 127.0.0.1 (as you said you don't want the local machine using the local DNS)? Would the `no-resolv` option for `dnsmasq` help? Have I completely missed the crux of your question?

Comment: The maschine runs no dns server _other than `dnsmasq`_. No, `no-resolv` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

1. `systemctl disable resolvconf.service`
2. `systemctl stop resolvconf.service`
3. `rm -f /etc/resolv.conf`
4. `echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' > /etc/resolv.conf  # or any other IP you want to use as DNS server`
5. `systemctl restart dnsmasq.service  # just for testing`
6. `cat /etc/resolv.conf  # just to verify`

The machine won't be able to get the DNS server address(es) via DHCP, but it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. On debian bullseye, when resolvconf is installed (which is the case by default, if I am not mistaken) then dnsmasq will have this behavior. You should edit the `/etc/default/dsnmasq` file and uncomment this line:

```
# If the resolvconf package is installed, dnsmasq will tell resolvconf
# to use dnsmasq under 127.0.0.1 as the system's default resolver.
# Uncommenting this line inhibits this behaviour.
#DNSMASQ_EXCEPT="lo"
```

into

```
# If the resolvconf package is installed, dnsmasq will tell resolvconf
# to use dnsmasq under 127.0.0.1 as the system's default resolver.
# Uncommenting this line inhibits this behaviour.
DNSMASQ_EXCEPT="lo"
```

It worked for me.